# Running script on instance that is created from AWS snapshot

Tags: amazon-ec2, scripting, startup

I've a AMI that I'd like to launch more instances based on this. But seems when I create instance based on this images, it doesn't boot-up. So the scripts that I would like to run on startup doesn't work. I've tested on /etc/rc.local /etc/init.d/myscript and record with @reboot on crontab but no luck. Probably my understanding of snapshot is not correct that it's actually not supposed to reboot right after it launches.

It there any way to reboot my instances in automatic way?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason canonical ubuntu on amazon doesn't come with cloud-init package installed. Even installing the package and run user-data it doesn't work. So I tried with amazon linux and it just works fine. Hope it helps if you are in a similar situation